# Hiding production passwords from unauthorized users in Symfony

Tags: symfony1

Symfony worked great for us when we were a small team of trusted developers. Now however, we are getting more people to help out, which leads to a problem with managing production passwords checked into source control.

I have production passwords for our DB, API keys, etc. stored in the Symfony config files which I do not want all developers to have access to. How can I hide these passwords from unauthorized developers and yet still grant them access to the source code?

Comment: Are you using some kind of version control like git or svn?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're already using a version control: your first stop should be removing all passwords from the history in your versioning system. Good luck ;-)

Next: isolate the files which have passwords in them. (Probably `config/databases.yml` and `apps/<yourapp>/app.yml`.).
Copy/rename this files to `*.yml.dist` (for example: `config/databases.yml.dist`). Clean up all production passwords from these files, and leave only
 the bare minimum to keep it going.

Make sure the original files don't appear in your VCS ever again. (`svn ignore`, or the likes).

Now when you set up a new environment, you can just copy the *.dist files to their 'real' names.

(What I did for my project is move all API keys to a single apikeys.yml in the `config` directory. That way all the properties in the `app.yml` keep being versioned, and my api keys don't appear in the VCS.

Comment: That's a good idea. But that would also mean that any changes I now make to the *.yml files would need to be copy-pasted manually to the *.dist files in each environment, right?

Comment: Yes. And that's why I chose to create only the *.dist files for the database configuration and the API keys. (So I could keep my app.yml, which changes a lot during development).

Answer (score -1):

Hope you get the answer for your question. Recently I have implement these kind of works in my project.I think to store these kind of confidential data **database** is the safe options and get this data using filter is the best option no need to store your data in app.yml.